# Ensure that a path is a directory path in Racket

Tags: shell, file, path, racket, filepath

Racket's path library treats files and directories a little differently. In Unix based Racket distributions, directories have a trailing `/` at the end. Several functions, such as [`in-directory`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-directory#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-directory%29%29) and [`path-only`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/More_Path_Utilities.html?q=path-only#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fpath..rkt%29._path-only%29%29) will use this information to treat paths leading to files and directories differently.

Unfortunately, the recommended way to create a path, [`build-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=build-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._build-path%29%29) does not have any good mechanism for creating a directory path. I know I could make a path as a string and use `string->path`, but that is going to be more brittle than using `build-path` directly:

```
> (string->path "a/b/")
#<path:a/b/>
```

Another thing I could do is combine `build-path` and `path-only` to add an extra 'trash' element to the path, which then gets stripped. But this is clunky as I then have to make that 'trash' string.

```
> (path-only (build-path "a" "b" "trash"))
#<path:a/b/>
```

I 'could' just put a `.` (or `'same`) in the `build-path` function, which ensures that its a directory path, but then the path itself has a `.` at the end, which can't even be removed with `path-only`:

```
> (build-path "a" "b" 'same)
#<path:a/b/.>
```

While all three of these can turn a path into a directory path, is there any cleaner way to turn an existing Racket path into a directory path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track by using `build-path`. The function you are looking for is [`path->directory-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Manipulating_Paths.html?q=build-path#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._path-~3edirectory-path%29%29). It takes a path object, and turns it into a directory path (in unix this means adding the trailing `/` you mentioned.

```
> (build-path "a" "b")
#<path:a/b>
> (path->directory-path (build-path "a" "b"))
#<path:a/b/>
```